# Upgrade to disc brakes

Tags: road-bike, brakes, disc-brake

I just got an older bike - a Schwinn Paramount Series 7 PGD OS bike.  It has 26" wheels.

What is required to convert to disc brakes? Any suggestions on which kit is best to get?

Are there any problems I might have with the conversion?

Comment: New frame, new fork, new wheels (hubs need to have rotor mounts), rotors, brake calipers and levers (these need to match).  Unfortunately a new bike would be more cost effective.

Comment: If you absolutely must have disk brakes, get another bike.  While conversion is in theory possible in many cases, the result will be an expensive mess.

Comment: To complement @Rider_X here's a list the parts that you might be able to reuse/keep - its a shorter list!   Pedals, saddle, lights, maybe seatpost, maybe handlebars, water bottle holder, maybe chain and transmission components, maybe tubes and tyres.

Comment: If you're not happy with the braking, buy new brake pads (and/or new brake calipers, which will come with new pads).

Comment: @Batman - cables as well.

Answer (score 5):

The photos I have seen on line indicate this bike lacks a frame mount for the rear brake caliper. The fork also lacks a mount. It will be most likely be cost prohibitive to attempt modifying the frame. You would need road specific disc calipers if you will be using drop bars, a disc wheelset, rotors, and cables as the old ones will likely be too short. If you are unhappy with the stopping ability the money would be better spent on quality brake pads.

Comment: Technically, you can use mountain brakes if you use a pulley (e.g. a travel agent). But the biger problem is getting everything on.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the slippery slope of knock-on upgrades.  Its cheaper to buy a new bike equipped with disks than it is to upgrade an existing bike to discs from rim brakes.

Look for Kool Stop brake pads for your existing rim brakes, which are often salmon-coloured.  They work really well, and aren't stupidly-expensive.

Don't buy $2 brake blocks and expect improvements.

Also, discs don't stop any better than rim brakes - so you might want to search this stack for "adjust rim brakes" and see if you can make yours work better.